# jQuery: pasting contents as plain text

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, paste

Using information on the internet, I got this far:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EeoFw

```
$('textarea').bind('paste', function () {
  var element = this;
  setTimeout(function () {
    var text = $(element).val();
        console.log("Paste")
  }, 100);
});
```

It seems to work just fine, but I was wondering what event I can trigger to basically put a "clean" version of the pasted text into the text area instead of the copied contents. This includes if text was pasted from HTML, Word or other sources. Is there a way to strip out tags and such without too much hassle? I'm guessing I'm looking for some kind of regex solution but I haven't been able to find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the styled content into a hidden div, and retrieve its `innerText`. If your styled content is in `text`:

```
a=document.createElement('div');
a.innerHTML=text;
b=a.innerText;
```